# How to get keyword status information from adwords api

Tags: google-ads-api

I am using the adwords php api hosted here https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib

It has got examples and I am using this one

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201309/BasicOperations/GetKeywords.php

that particular example fetches keywords in a given adgroup using the adgroup id and customerid.

The keyword information does not contain the status of the keyword, i.e. ACTIVE/PAUSED

How to get that ?

The selectable fields do not seem to have a field for current status. The list is here

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/selectorfields#v201309-AdGroupCriterionService

So how do I get the current status of the keywords when fetching them using the get method of AdGroupCriterionService ?

Answer (score 1):

A keyword's status can be selected in AdGroupCriterionService by adding 'UserStatus' to the array of fields in your selector.

Specifically, in the example doc you mentioned above, change this:

```
$selector->fields = array('KeywordText', 'KeywordMatchType', 'Id');
```

to this:

```
$selector->fields = array('KeywordText', 'KeywordMatchType', 'Id', 'UserStatus');
```

Comment: It's not `UserStatus`, it's just `Status`. See https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201502/AdGroupCriterionService.BiddableAdGroupCriterion#userStatus. The property is `UserStatus` but the value to select is: `This field can be selected using the value "Status".`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [BiddableAdGroupCriterion](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201309/AdGroupCriterionService.BiddableAdGroupCriterion). This is a sub-class of the [AdGroupCriterion](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201309/AdGroupCriterionService.AdGroupCriterion).

One of the properties of the [BiddableAdGroupCriterion](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201309/AdGroupCriterionService.BiddableAdGroupCriterion) is [UserStatus](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201309/AdGroupCriterionService.UserStatus). This is an enum with three possible values: `ACTIVE`, `DELETED` or `PAUSED`.

This should be what you're after.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The status is on the parent class object AdGroupCriterion. Here is an example:

```
$selector->fields = array('Id', 'KeywordText', 'KeywordMatchType', 'AdGroupId', 'Status');
...
    foreach ($page->entries as $adGroupCriterion) {
      $adGroupCriterion->userStatus
      $keyword = $adGroupCriterion->criterion;
```